# Best way to handle large amount of permanent data

Tags: c#, windows-8.1

I'm developing a PC app in Visual Studio where I'm showing the status of hundreds of sensors that are connected via WiFi. The thing is that I need to hold on to the sensor data even after I close the app, so I'm considering some form of permanent storage. These are the options I've considered:

1) My Sensor object is relatively compact with only a few properties. I could serialize all the objects before closing the app and load them every time the app starts anew.

2) I could throw all the properties (which are mostly strings and doubles) into a simple text file and create a custom protocol for storage and retrieval.

3) I could integrate a database with my app. Someone told me this is the best way to go about it, but I'm a bit hesitant seeing as I'm not familiar with DBs.

Which method would yield the best results in terms of resource usage and speed? Or is there some other, better way to go about this?

Comment: Well Databases are designed to store data, more-so they do it in a way that means you don't need to worry about the underlying storage format or mechanism.  The well defined SQL interface means you have many options when it comes to doing fun stuff/analysis/sharing the data later on.

Comment: Are you gonna store a historical log of the sensors data or the configuration of the sensors?

Comment: This seems like a classic meta-problem. "I want to store information X". That is pretty useless as a question, as you could just "pipe it to `\dev\null`". Storing data is useless. You need to be able to read the data for it to be useful. How do you intend to USE the data?

Comment: @MennanKara Yes I plan to keep a historical log of the data sent by the sensors. Its basically for a security system so I'm not expecting data to be coming in all the time (only when an alarm triggers). As far as usage goes, I have an image of the map of the area and each sensor is represented as a dot on top of the image; each time a sensor triggers I need the app to respond (dot turns red, sound alert etc.). Additionally there's an option to add new sensors and obviously I want the app to hold onto all the sensors once it closes.

Comment: Basically I want the app to hold on to the details about each sensor (its ID,  latitude/longitude) and a historical log that stores the time and date of each sensor every time it triggers for some reason.

Comment: As far as the actual amount of data goes, there'll be a max of 1000 sensors (probably actually around 500), and I won't need to maintain logs for more than a month in the past. Each "sensor" object itself only contains a few strings and doubles properties.

Comment: You might wanna use MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need is to understand is your problem. For example, when the program is running do you need to have everything in memory at the same time or do you work with your sensors one at a time?

What is a "large amount of data"? For example, to me that will never be less than million (or billion in some cases).

Once you know that you shouldn't be scared of using something just because you are not familiar to it. Otherwise you are not looking for the best solution for your problem, you are just hacking around it in a way that you feel comfortable.

This being said, you have several ways of doing this. Like you said you can serialize data, using json to store and a few other alternatives but if we are talking about a "large amount of data that we want to persist" I would always call for the use of Databases (the name says a lot). If **you don't need to have everything in memory at the same time** then I believe that this is you best option.

I personally don't like them (again, personal choice) but one way of not learning SQL (a lot) while you still use your objects is to use an ORM like NHibernate (you will also need to learn how to use it so you don't get things a slower).

If you need to have everything loaded at the same time (most often that is not the case so be sure of this) you need to know what you want to keep and serialize it. If you want that data to be readable by another tool or organize in a given way consider a data format like XML or JSON.

Comment: Sorry for the rather ambiguous question, I've added details in the comments on the reply above.

Comment: Considering your comments I do believe you want to use a database. The amount of data you are talking is quite small so you have quite a few alternatives and I don't believe performance will be critical (otherwise you would have to understand a bit more of databases). NoSQL (MongoDB, like Mennan Kara suggested), SQL (Sqlite, MySql), SQL with a ORM are just a few of several alternatives. You should take a look around Databases though.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use mmap-file. 
File is permanent, and keep data between program run.
So, you just keep your data structs in the mmap-ed area, and no more.

MSDN manual here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to load all the data once at the start of the program, the database case seems doubtful. The DB necessary when you need to load a bit of data many times.

So first two cases seem more preferred. I would advice to hide a specific solution behind an interface, then you'll can change it later.

Standard .NET serialization of sensors' array is more simple probably, and it will be easier to expand.